# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined (print map with geoserver)

Tags: javascript, extjs, printing, openlayers, geoserver

am trying to work with print with geoserver geoext/ext to print a map.
i successed to install the print plugin, since localhost:8080/geoserver/pdf/info.json?var=printCapabilities shows the print capabilities.
THE PROBLEM: when i try to load the page with the map and the print button i get this error:

```
   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined ext-all.js:21
   Ext.extend.readRecords ext-all.js:21
   Ext.data.Store.Ext.extend.loadData ext-all.js:21
   GeoExt.data.PrintProvider.Ext.extend.loadStores PrintProvider.js:548
   GeoExt.data.PrintProvider.Ext.extend.constructor PrintProvider.js:342
   (anonymous function) TestPrint.html:22
   (anonymous function) ext-all.js:21
   b
```

i can't figure out the problem so here's my TestPrint.html:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
  <html>
  <head>
    <title>
       A map
    </title>
<script src="../ext-3.4.1/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../ext-3.4.1/ext-all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../ext-3.4.1/resources/css/ext-all.css">
<script src="../openlayers/OpenLayers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../openlayers/lib/deprecated.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../GeoExt/lib/GeoExt.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../GeoExt/resources/css/geoext-all-debug.css">
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

 var mapPanel, printDialog;

 Ext.onReady(function() {
// The PrintProvider that connects us to the print service
var printProvider = new GeoExt.data.PrintProvider({   **// this is line 22**
    method: "GET", // "POST" recommended for production use
    capabilities: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/pdf/info.json?var=printCapabilities", // provide url instead for lazy loading
    customParams: {
        mapTitle: "GeoExt Printing Demo",
        comment: "This demo shows how to use GeoExt.PrintMapPanel"
    }
});

// A MapPanel with a "Print..." button
mapPanel = new GeoExt.MapPanel({
    renderTo: "content",
    width: 500,
    height: 350,
    map: {
        maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(
            143.835, -43.648,
            148.479, -39.574
        ),
        maxResolution: 0.018140625,
        projection: "EPSG:4326",
        units: 'degrees'
    },
    layers: [new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Tasmania State Boundaries",
        "http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms",
        {layers: "topp:tasmania_state_boundaries"},
        {singleTile: true, numZoomLevels: 8})],
    center: [146.56, -41.56],
    zoom: 0,
    bbar: [{
        text: "Print...",
        handler: function(){
            // A window with the PrintMapPanel, which we can use to adjust
            // the print extent before creating the pdf.
            printDialog = new Ext.Window({
                title: "Print Preview",
                layout: "fit",
                width: 350,
                autoHeight: true,
                items: [{
                    xtype: "gx_printmappanel",
                    sourceMap: mapPanel,
                    printProvider: printProvider
                }],
                bbar: [{
                    text: "Create PDF",
                    handler: function(){ printDialog.items.get(0).print(); }
                }]
            });
            printDialog.show();
        }
    }]
});

 });

</script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id='content'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the docs, here: http://geoext.org/lib/GeoExt/data/PrintProvider.html

It says **capabilities** is the actual object returned from the url, so you could probably just give the url to the **url** property. That is, change line 24 from:

```
capabilities: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/pdf/info.json?var=printCapabilities", // provide url instead for lazy loading
```

to:

```
url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/pdf/info.json?var=printCapabilities", // provide url instead for lazy loading
```

No guarantee that will solve all your problems, though. Otherwise I would set a break point with firebug or so on line 22 and step debug.

Comment: yes chris thank you it worked, but i still have problem with print button, when i click on it i get an error should i post it here or ask a new question?

Comment: i have an error on line 247 in PrintMapPanel.js specially in the function  adjustSize: function(width, height) here's the line" var printSize = this.printProvider.layout.get("size");"  the error is : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of null

Comment: Well it means this.printProvider.layout is null. Please check that your input parameters are all according to the documentation.

Comment: Where to check parameters? and which parameters? because i define everything concerning the map. but this size i don't know what it means :s

Comment: I would suggest you to use a debugger like firebug (http://getfirebug.com/javascript) and step a breakpoint on the offending line, then you can look at the stack trace and hopefully see what was expected. I cannot give you a reply top off my head, sorry.